# How to switch SceneBuilder by clicking on a HBox instead of a button

Tags: java, javafx

I am new in javafx and i am confused. Im actually trying to switch SceneBuilders with a navigation menu that i made with HBoxes. Each page direction has a HBox. I noticed that there is no event "onAction" with HBoxes without this i don't know how can i do this switch. Is it possible to do that without using buttons ?
[Here is an example of how it looks like, i want to go to all those different pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAlVv.png)

Comment: All i want is to go from a fxml to another one by clicking on a HBox. But there is not "onAction"  event in Scene Builder so i don't know how i can i detect the click on the HBox to put the code for the redirection

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/RestaurantOrdersDuplicateFX

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setOnMouseClicked or similar method. I am not sure is you can define this in the scene builder, but in the code for sure.

Since Hbox extends node, there is a majority of similar inherited methods. You can find it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html) under the section

'Methods inherited from class javafx.scene.Node'